# Can't pass request parameters using http post

Tags: java, spring

I have a requirement to call a controller from java code itself. The controller is as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "temp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadDataFromExcel(@RequestBody Map<String, String> colMapObj, @ModelAttribute ReqParam reqParam) {
}
```

I am trying to call the above controller using http post as follows,

```
String url ="http://localhost:8081/LeadM" + "/temp/?searchData="+ reqParam.getSearchData()+" &exportDiscardRec=" + reqParam.isExportDiscardRec() + "&fileName=" + reqParam.getFileName() + "&sheetName=" + reqParam.getSheetName() +  "&importDateFormat=" + reqParam.getImportDateFormat()  + "&selectedAddressTypes="+ reqParam.getSelectedAddressTypes() + "&duplicatesHandleOn=" + reqParam.getDuplicatesHandleOn() + colMapObj;

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream rstream = entity.getContent();
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(rstream));
```

where reqParam is a class object is the class object and colMapObj is the map that I want to pass to the above controller. However when http post is executed it gives exception in the url. 
If anybody knows the right way then please suggest, thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide exception stack?

Comment: @Jags java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 78: http://localhost:8081/LeadM/app/lead/uploadDataFromExcelImportVm/?searchData=[" . Precisely it is after searchData=             Thanks

Comment: do you care responding what worked and what not? People spend time to help you and acknowledgement/appreciation is great way to motivate and help others.

Comment: @Jags sorry for the delay actually I was stuck somewhere else after some time of this posting. I am trying each and every suggestion now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL dos not work with spaces.From your code above: " &exportDiscardRec=" 
To avoid such issues use **URIBuilder** or something similar if possible.

Now for the request, you are not building your request correctly for example you do not provide the body. 
Check below example:

```
    Map<String, String> colMapObj = new HashMap<>();
    colMapObj.put("testKey", "testdata");

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    JSONObject body = new JSONObject(colMapObj);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body.toString());
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    System.out.println(response.getEntity().toString());
    client.close();
```

More examples just google "apache http client post examples" (e.g. http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request)

Comment: Thanks @LenosV I was successfull to hit the desired controller using above method, but I was not able to map the ReqParam object. How can I use URIBuilder in this case as this object contains jsonarray, boolean, string all mixed type of data. Thanks

Comment: Got it, I converted everyting in ReqParm to string.I userd URIBuilder for ReqParam object and for colMapObj I used as stated above. Many thanks @LenosV and everyone

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/temp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadDataFromExcel(@RequestBody Map<String, String> colMapObj, @ModelAttribute ReqParam reqParam) {
}
```

and url should be

```
String url ="http://localhost:8081/LeadM" + "/temp?"+ reqParam.getSearchData()+" &exportDiscardRec=" + reqParam.isExportDiscardRec() + "&fileName=" + reqParam.getFileName() + "&sheetName=" + reqParam.getSheetName() +  "&importDateFormat=" + reqParam.getImportDateFormat() + "&selectedAddressTypes="+ reqParam.getSelectedAddressTypes() + "&duplicatesHandleOn=" + reqParam.getDuplicatesHandleOn() + colMapObj;
```

Comment: Thanks @Prakash Jethava actually the same url is being used in angularjs for the original purpose of hitting the controller. So there is no issue with it

Answer (score 1):

Encode your query string.

```
String endpoint = "http://localhost:8081/LeadM/tmp?";
String query = "searchData="+ reqParam.getSearchData()+" &exportDiscardRec=" + reqParam.isExportDiscardRec() + "&fileName=" + reqParam.getFileName() + "&sheetName=" + reqParam.getSheetName() +  "&importDateFormat=" + reqParam.getImportDateFormat()  + "&selectedAddressTypes="+ reqParam.getSelectedAddressTypes() + "&duplicatesHandleOn=" + reqParam.getDuplicatesHandleOn() + colMapObj;

String q = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");

String finalUrl = endpoint + q;
```

If this doesn't work, then encode individual params before concatenating.

On a side note

1. if you r running in same jvm then you can call method directly
2. if you own the the upload method then consider changing query string into form param

Comment: I tried the above like  String query = "http://localhost:8081/LeadM/import/uploadDataFromExcelImportVm/?searchData="+ reqParam.getSearchData()+" &exportDiscardRec=   and String q = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"); then HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(q); but it gave me exception like org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

Comment: Also how can we change the query string to form param, can you please show a snippet

Comment: Complete exception is Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified.

Comment: @AJN do not include `"http://localhost:8081/LeadM/tmp?"` in your `query` variable. I updated my example.

Comment: Thanks @Jags got it. Thank you very much